# Reduce to lowest possible gates

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to reduce (¬A V ¬B) V (A ⊕ B ) to be expressed by the lowest possible number of gates. So far by expanding the XOR gate and using Demorgan's and distributive laws, I have come down to this
¬(A ∧ B) V (A V B)
Is it possible to reduce this even further?

Comment: Forgot to add, I need to express this using only AND, OR and NOT gates only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\overline A+\overline B +A \oplus B = \overline A+\overline B +\overline A B + A\overline B=\overline A(1+B)+\overline B(1+A)=\overline A+\overline B=\overline {AB}$